# extract(week from 'Now') error

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm running an firebird 2.5 superclassic on my raspberrypi. I execute the following query and it gives the following error:

```
SELECT foodmanager1.F_US_FIRSTNAME,foodmanager1.F_US_LASTNAME, 
foodmanager1.F_US_PICTURE_URL,
foodmanager2.F_US_FIRSTNAME, foodmanager2.F_US_LASTNAME, 
foodmanager2.F_US_PICTURE_URL,
duty.F_US_FIRSTNAME, duty.F_US_LASTNAME,
duty.F_US_PICTURE_URL,
a.F_FD_DATE from
    T_FOOD_DUTY a
inner join T_USER foodmanager1 on a.F_US_ID1 = foodmanager1.F_US_ID
inner join T_USER foodmanager2 on a.F_US_ID2 = foodmanager2.F_US_ID
inner join T_USER duty on a.F_US_ID3 = duty.F_US_ID
where extract(week from a.F_FD_DATE) = extract(week from 'Now')
```

With this error:

> Specified EXTRACT part does not exist in input datatype

SQL error code=~105.

I know the problem is with the `extract(week from 'Now')`, because when I manually replace it with a number I do get some results.

Any idea what the problem is, or do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `extract` accepts any data type, but only works for types `date`, `time` or `timestamp`. In this context, `'Now'` is simply a `char(3)`, so extract cannot be used (it can't extract data from a `char` type).

The confusion stems from the fact that in some contexts (eg assignment or explicit cast to a `date`, `time` or `timestamp`), `'Now'` will yield the current date/time. It does not work in this context, because Firebird can't know which of the three types it would need to be; in theory `extract` accepts any type, what it can actually do is determined by the type it receives.

You need to explicitly coerce it to a `date` (or `timestamp`):

1. Using an explicit cast:

   ```
   extract(week from cast('Now' as date))
   ```
2. Using a type-introducer (aka shorthand cast):

   ```
   extract(week from date'Now')
   ```
3. Or, as suggested in the [answer of ain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44197698/466862), use the SQL standard 'function' `current_date` or `current_timestamp`:

   ```
   extract(week from current_date)
   ```

Comment: option 2 - is it documented? the most similar thing I saw was specifying encoding/collation for string literal constants. But specifying types like that - I think the first time I see it in FB

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes it is: [Shorthand Casts for Date and Time Data Types](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-conversion.html#fblangref25-datatypes-convert-shortcasts), this is also specified in the SQL standard (although there it is defined for format `'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'`, not for things like `'now'`).

Answer (score 3):

Use the SQL standard `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (or `CURRENT_DATE` as the time part is not important when extracting the week) instead of `'NOW'`

```
extract(week from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Or if you really want to use `'NOW'` then cast it to date:

```
extract(week from CAST('Now' AS DATE))
```

Comment: I 'borrowed' your suggestion to use `current_timestamp`, hope you don't mind :)